# Some ips can establish tcp connections to a server with DROP iptables rules

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-14.04

I am hired to fix hacking issue for a server, I found that ip 37.187.253.240 and some other ips can connect to specific port, while they are not allowed !.

csf firewall is installed in the server, and that port is not open for all in csf.conf.

only some ips are added in list csf.allow .

current iptables status by `iptables -L` is : 
INPUT Chain (DROP policy), with ACCEPT only for some ips. and this ip 37.187.253.240 hasn't any rule.

to make sure that the csf isn't the cause if I stop csf by `csf -x` and flush the iptables rules by `iptables -F` , then added only a DROP rule `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 37.187.253.240 -j DROP` for that ip , I see it can connect also via netstat

```
tcp        0     0 myip:port    37.187.253.240:16132    ESTABLISHED
```

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
, hosted in vmware.com.

what are the probabilities of this case ?

Comment: Did you look at all iptables rules / chains? You may be missing something there! You are dropping by source IP and then showing `netstat` output where the same IP is the remote address!! This seems confusing.

Comment: I have tried to grep the ip from netstat, I don't miss any thing, and this is not the first time for me to configure the firewall.